# Problem with using Physics.Raycast to check if grounded

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a multiplayer FPS with Unity 2018 and I'm trying to detect if grounded using a raycast to see whether the player can jump or not.

I've written a function which should work based on multiple guides, but it returns seemingly random values whether the player is actually grounded or not.

My function:

```
bool IsGrounded()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, 1f))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Miss");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: will it return "Hit" stably when the player is actually grounded? if so, maybe your ray casting will randomly hit some objects of the player itself. try move your player to some specified layer, and ignore it in the layer mask.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I believe `1f` is hitting your `Player`.  Add a layermask to exclude your player, make `1f` Mathf.Infinity for now since I believe it is too small, and use `Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -transform.up * 1f, Color.RED)` to see just how long `1f` really is.

Comment: @ZhangQi "Hit" is not stable whether grounded or not.

Comment: @jiveturkey I'll do that now.

Comment: @jiveturkey That works thank you! Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct please?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your comment not, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SgtOddball I had a similar issue. I believe 1f is hitting your Player. 
Add a `layermask` to exclude your player, make 1f `Mathf.Infinity` for now since I believe it is too small, and use

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -transform.up * 1f, Color.RED)
```

to see just how long 1f really is. I don't believe it is.